# How can I make this chart using ApexChart or any other JS libraries?

Tags: charts, chart.js, apexcharts

the problem is, how to format points as dates, it accepts only integers
i tried this but this is what i get,, see the pic below

```
var options = {
        series: [
                 {
                        name: "Expected",
                        data: [
                            @foreach($main_timelines as $main_timeline)
                            {
                                x: '{{$main_timeline->name}}',
                                y: {{\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($main_timeline->expected_dedline)->format('Ymd')}}
                            },
                            @endforeach
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Actual",
                        data: [
                                @foreach($main_timelines as $main_timeline)
                            {
                                x: '{{$main_timeline->name}}',
                                y: {{\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($main_timeline->actual_dedline)->format('Ymd')}},
                            },
                            @endforeach
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                chart: {
                    height: 350,
                    type: 'area',
                    animations: {
                        speed: 500
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                stroke: {
                    curve: 'straight',
                },
                yaxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function (value, timestamp) {
                            var string = ''+value
                            var year = string.substr(0, 4)
                            var month = string.substr(4, 2)
                            var day = string.substr(6, 2)
                            return year+'-'+month
                        },
                    }
                },
                colors: [primary, success]
            };
```

[image]

The following picture shows the desired graph
[image]

Is there a way to create the graph in the image above using ApexChart or any other JS library?